# Div box not expanding on overflow

Tags: css, html

I have the following html (not proper code but for understanding)

```
<div id=content-wrap overflow-hidden>
<div1 float-left overflow hidden> </div>
<div2 float-right overflow hidden> </div>

</div>
```

Now when the content in div 1 is more, then it expands the main container but by div2 which is on the right is not expanding

Is there any way so that div2 also expands with div1 without changing the html

Comment: proper html and css will more helpful to answer...

Comment: agreed would liek to see some proper html and CSS.

Why do you need overflow:hidden on all divs?  Surely you only need it on the parent div?

Also you may need to reapply hasLayout in IE if using overflow:hidden.

Comment: I'm sorry, you want it so when DIV1 expands, DIV2 expands as well?

Comment: Actually the design and css s very big, don't know hich code to post.
is there anything like height 100%. beacuse when parent div expand with div1 , the div2 height remains short , it does not expands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do that with CSS 2.1 is to use display table:

```
#content-wrap {
    display: table-row;
}
#content-wrap div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

The reason why most people don't use it is that it doesn't work in IE6 & 7, also you'll need an extra wrapper element for the `display: table` declaration for everything to work properly.

An alternative approach with CSS3 is to use [flexboxes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/):

```
#content-wrap {
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: box;
}
#content-wrap div {
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
}
```

--Edit

Now that I'm older and wiser, you actually only need this for the `display: table` approach:

```
#content-wrap {
    display: table;
}
#content-wrap div {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

It should work with your current markup, the layout engine will insert an [anonymous table object](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes) to take on the `table-row` role.

Also note the flex box draft changed significantly recently, but browsers are still on the old draft.

Answer (score 1):

You will need javascript to make this work. You won't be able to fix this with CSS.
What you can do, is give both 'columns' a height of 100%, but I don't think that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to throw in some CSS3 (not supported in all browsers) you could do something found here: http://www.css3.info/preview/multi-column-layout/

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible with divs. Tables solve the problem. When div1 expands, it is impossible to expand div2 also ! using some javascript will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is worth a shot:

```
#content-wrap { position: relative; }
#div2 { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; }
```

I don't think this technique works in IE6, and it doesn't seem to work in every circumstance, but I stumbled upon it about a week ago. Essentially, you're telling the top and bottom of the element to be at the maximums, so it stretches. Note that this will only work *without* a fixed height.